# Converting view with toolbar from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I have an AppCompatActivity screen with toolbar, navigation drawer and custom view in content. I want to display a configuration. I shall not use dialog as it will be large and will open dialogs. My friend advised me to rewrite the code to have two fragments and switch between them.

Current code:

```
public class PuzzleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

activity_puzzle.xml (reduced)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_puzzle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_main" />
```

app_bar_puzzle.xml (reduced)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<include layout="@layout/content_puzzle" />
```

And finally content_puzzle.xml (again reduced, and for simplicity custom view replaced with textView)

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Content"/>
```

Originally I created a Fragment and replaced android.R.id.content with this fragment: I end up with overlapping fragment and original view:

[image]

I had  a theory that that was caused by FragmentManager unable to replace activity view defined from XML or incompatibility between Activity view and fragments. So I decided to introduce new Fragment and move all UI to this fragment.

PuzzleFragment.java derived from support library:

```
public class PuzzleFragment extends Fragment {    
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_puzzle, container, false);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();    

        return view;
    }
```

But this fails on a toolbar initialization:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:98)
at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:91)
at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:73)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:205)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
at PuzzleFragment.onCreateView(PuzzleFragment.java:30)
```

The toolbar is null, `findViewById` does not find it in the Fragment /`inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_puzzle, container, false`)/. But it does if it is in the Activity /`setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle)`/.

How can I make it work?

Comment: *Originally I created a Fragment and replaced android.R.id.content...* - why exactly are you doing this if the content of your activity is in the content_puzzle layout? In that layout you should have a container where the fragments with the content will be placed.

Comment: I created new FrameLayout and set it in the Activity with setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle_fragments) and transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new PuzzleFragment(). It still fails the same way.

Comment: Keep you current setup. Give an id to the RelativeLayout in the content_puzzle.xml file(I'm assuming it's the root of the layout). Then remove whatever views you had in that RelativeLayout and inflate them as the contents of a fragment. You can then use a transaction to add the created fragment to the above RelativeLayout(and later replace it, do another transaction etc).

Comment: I commented out all parts that fail and Navigation Drawer with TexView were displayed. Toolbar was missing. It looks that findById finds nothing within Fragment's onCreateView.

Comment: I moved this initialization to onActivityCreated - and it started to work! Good progress.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to move initialization procedure to later phase as shown in the source code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(logTag, "onCreateView()");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_puzzle, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(logTag, "onActivityCreated()");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```